# How does Morphology apply to reading and teaching English Language Learners how to read?

Tags: english, morphology

I am not sure if I am answering the question correctly can anyone please comment.

Morphology is the study of words.   It deals with understanding of word parts (morphemes).  To facilitate student’s learning and help develop their vocabulary it can be helpful to use a morphological approach.  This approach would allows student build on their current vocabulary by adding prefixes and suffixes to root words.

Comment: There is very little regular morphology in English. Almost all the morphology is derivational, and therefore irregular and not paradigmatic. I wouldn't mention much morphology to E-L learners; syntax and phonology are what they need to learn.

Comment: Pedro, does that definitely answers your question? If so, @jlawler can you turn it into an answer? Thank you.

Comment: I appreciate jlawer comment. Its a lot more to the whole terminology.

Answer (score 2):

Skilled readers are known to rely on morphology to help them segment words and support fluent reading. However, it doesn't matter whether this segmentation is correct. For instance, the -er in 'teacher' and in 'corner' is equally useful for somebody who is trying to quickly decode those words. Somebody who cannot do that will have to develop a greater inventory of words they have to learn to read as disconnected chunks.

Any way that can support learners metacognition is likely to be helpful in reading as well as writing and speaking. Showing both first language and additional language students the principles of word formation is likely to be extremely helpful for any language (perhaps even more so in English where segmentation at the level of morphemes can help overcome the irregularities at the level of grapheme-phoneme correspondence). Just be aware that the point is not to get the analysis right as long as you can use the analytic strategy to help you with a word or an expression.